# Get columns from CSV as regex groups

Tags: regex

Not used to play a lot with regex, but now its really causing me a headache.

I have a multi line CSV file where I need to find a line which starts with a specific value in the first field and then have the groups for all the remaining fields of that line even if some fields are empty.
The length of the CSV could variate

So for example:

```
monday,1,8,nice,,sunny,cold,
tuesday,3,2,hello,bye,,sad,tomorrow,
wednesday,8,ok,4,xxx,,999,welcome,
```

I want to match the CSV line which starts with "tuesday" and have all the fields excluding the first one matching groups so:

```
Group1 = 3
Group2 = 2
Group3 = hello
Group4 = bye
Group5 = 
Group6 = sad
Group7 = tomorrow
```

Unfortunately I am stuck to regex because the tool only handles regex. Parsing it with a few lines of code in Go would be much easier, but its simply not possible in this situation.

Found some help on IRC group, it works but only with a fixed length CSV string:

```
^tuesday,([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]*),([^,]+),([^,]+),$
```

Could it be done with a variable length as well?

Thanks

Comment: What programming language are you using? You do not need a regex - just compare the first characters with "tuesday," and then return the rest of the line. Then shop the line on a comma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number of columns is fixed then this will work:

```
^tuesday,([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)
```

It finds lines that start with *tuesday* and creates 7 groups that catches everything that is not a `,`.

You can check it here: https://regexr.com/3pn81.

Comment: Thank you, it works indeed, I will need to reformat my input format slightly but it will do as well.

Comment: No that will not work, if a field contains a comma enclosed by double quotes. For example `tuesday,","` is valid CSV format, that your regex does not match on.

Comment: @tim-montague CSV format has many quirks. OP asked for regex for specific case. If you need to parse arbitrary csv file just use `csv` module.

Comment: I'm using this regex for a Find and Replace on a CSV file from my command line. Installing a `csv` package and writing the code would be a slower process.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files often contain fields with commas in double quotes, so I would avoid `([^,]+)` and `([^,]*)`. You can use `(.*?)` to capture fields without commas, and `(".*?")` to capture fields with commas.

So for example to capture `tuesday,3,","` write the pattern:

```
^tuesday,(.*?),(".*?")
```

Which captures:

```
$1=3 $2=","
```

> Could it be done with a variable length as well?

I thought something like `{n}` to indicate the number of capture groups might work...

```
^(.*?),{n}
```

...but no luck. And from what I'm reading it may not be possible.